# Change the cursor to pointer when hover on the background image using CSS

Tags: css

I have a background image inside a div. This background image only covers a part of the div. Is there a way to change the cursor to a pointer only when the background image is hovered?

Top left square is the background image.
[image]

This is the HTML code for the div.

```
<div class="checkbox-container see-value-demo-checkbox">
    1-hour recording <a href="/courses/71"><b>Media and Optimization Workshop</b></a>  
    (Optimized for technical teams)
</div>
```

The background image is set using CSS.

```
.checkbox-container {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    background-image: url(/ui-icons/Checbox-Not-Selected-Grey.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

I am aware that this can be done by wrapping the background image into another smaller div. But the there are 100s of `checkbox-container` divs and I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this using CSS or JS without any structural change.

Comment: Depend, if they all look alike, and the background appear in the same fixed location with fixed width/height like above, then yes, it can be done. Otherwise i can't think of anything

Comment: @Eezo - yes, they appear in the same location with fixed width and height like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with everything fixed, you can create a "fake" layout in the place of the image using `:before`

```css
.checkbox-container {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    background-image: url(/ui-icons/Checbox-Not-Selected-Grey.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    padding-left: 40px;
      position: relative;
    width: 200px; /* Just for the sake of the demo */
}
.checkbox-container:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 30px; /* Just demo, you can change it to match your image size */
      height: 30px; /* Just demo, you can change it to match your image size */
      background: green; /* Just demo since i can't show the image, you can delete it later */
    border-radius: 6px; /* Just demo, you can change it to match your image radius or outright delete it, doesn't matter much */
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container see-value-demo-checkbox">
    1-hour recording <a href="/courses/71"><b>Media and Optimization Workshop</b></a>  
    (Optimized for technical teams)
</div>
```